# TPS61178 Input Current Limit

Tags: boost, switching-regulator

I am working with [TI TPS61778](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61178.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1692884836131&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Ftps61178) and the title of the part says it has a 10 A switch current. This is all fine and dandy but in the electrical specifications, we see that for a RLIMIT of 80.6 k we have a I_LIM(min) of 6.4 A to a maximum of 9.4 A. This is a huge range of currents and is the difference between my load working or not. Is this I_LIM(min) value specifying the average current through the switch? Which value should I be designing with?

Answer (score 0):

From the datasheet:

[image]

So you can compute the average current limit by knowing the p-p current ripple in the inductor for your conditions.  The ILIM minimum is the minimum PEAK current limit that you could have given the 80.6 k resistor value.